# StringTokenizer get the third element

Tags: android, stringtokenizer

I am very new to android..Can you please help me to solve this.
I have a string like

```
DOCOMOBH-TATA DOCOMO Mobile Bihar-SRSBL53-DOCOMOBH
```

and I have to get the third element. i.e SRSBL53

I have done this.

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(billerlist, "-");
String strBillerId = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
```

Thus i have got the first element DOCOMOBH.but how to get the third one.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `split(regex)` on your `String`

```
String billerlist = "DOCOMOBH-TATA DOCOMO Mobile Bihar-SRSBL53-DOCOMOBH";

String[] array = billerlist.split("-");
if(array.length>2){
    String thirdElement = array[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TextUtils.StringSplitter`, a `StringTokenizer` would have to read at least n tokens in order to determine which is the n-th one. Thus it might be easier to just create a string array using `StringSplitter`

```
TextUtils.StringSplitter splitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter("-");

splitter.setString(billerList);
if(splitter.size>2){
    String myString = splitter[2];
}
```

Comment: For refernce visit: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.StringSplitter.html

Answer (score 0):

Optimized answer is provided by others but for the sake of answering what you are trying see the following code

```
    String billerlist = "DOCOMOBH-TATA DOCOMO Mobile Bihar-SRSBL53-DOCOMOBH";
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(billerlist, "-");
    String requiredData = null; //local variables must be initialized before using
     int count = 1;
    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String data = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        if(count == 3) {
            requiredData = data;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if(requiredData != null) {
        System.out.println("Required data is " + requiredData);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Required data not present");
    }
```

and the output is

```
Required data is SRSBL53
```